# Kafka HTTP Sink Connector giving 415 error

Tags: c#, apache-kafka-connect

I am new to Kafka connect. In one of our application we decided to use HTTP Sink Connector where data will be consumed from a particular topic and will be sent to an API created in .net.

Data produced in Kafka topic is as per avro schema.

Below is the HTTP sink connector configuration.

```
{
"name": "HTTPSinkConnector_1",
"config": {
    "topics": "test_data_topic_1",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.http.HttpSinkConnector",
    "http.api.url": "http://localhost/messageHandler",
    "request.method": "post",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:19092",
    "confluent.topic.replication.factor": "1",
    "reporter.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:19092",
    "reporter.result.topic.name": "success-responses",
    "reporter.result.topic.replication.factor": "1",
    "reporter.error.topic.name": "error-responses",
    "reporter.error.topic.replication.factor": "1"
}
```

}

Avro Schema:

```
{
"fields": [
    {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "string"
    },
    {
        "name": "name",
        "type": "string"
    }
],
"name": "article",
"namespace": "test.data",
"type": "record"
```

}

In the .net API I have created the dto as per above avro schema using avrogen. In the POST call function the receiver object is of that dto class.

[image]

The HTTP Sink connector is throwing an `415: unsupported media type` error. Could some one please help me what's wrong in config and how message will be received in .net api.

I have also tested the below request to check the endpoint and it is working fine.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost/messageHandler' --header 'Content-Type: text/json' --data-raw '{"id": "11", "name": "hello"}'
```

Comment: Typo? `-H Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Removed Kafka tags because your error comes from your own API, and you're not showing sending data to Kafka... More specifically, your API doesn't accept Avro. Looks like it accepts plaintext or JSON. You'll want to edit your server accept octet-stream content type for Avro

Comment: @OneCricketeer  Error is being thrown in the kakfa connect logs. Would it be possible for you to suggest what should be type of the receiver object. I am not able to figure it out what is the content-type for the message sent by HTTP Sink Connector. I had added kafka tags because others who uses kafka might have faced similar issues and will be able to help

Comment: You've configured Connect with AvroConverter. And you're producing Avro. Therefore, it's binary, **not json**, so your test isn't valid. Your server needs to accept binary (application/octet-stream) via Content Negotiation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation  Or, you need to produce JSON instead of Avro and use JSONConverter